# Windows update restarts the computer reason 0x80020002

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, reboot

```
The process C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe Computer Name has initiated the restart of computer Computer Name  on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason:
Operating System: Recovery (Planned)
Reason Code: 0x80020002
Shutdown Type: restart
Event ID : 1074
```

I use this computer to run simulations overnight and automatically restarting ruins all my progress. I am not allowed to disable windows updates, how can I make it so that windows will never reboot on its own?

Comment: "how can I make it so that windows will never reboot on its own?" - Disable Windows Update, and install all updates, through your own WSUS server.  This way you control which updates are released and when they are released.  You can also use something like WSUS Offline.  You can also configure Windows 7 to prompt you to install updates, which might be the simplest, for a non-technical user.

Comment: Related: https://www.petri.com/forums/forum/server-operating-systems/windows-server-2008-2008-r2/60662-server-restart-reason-code-0x80020002